# Delete button next to each array's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a HTML-JavaScript script in which the user can insert data to a new array `[]` by using a form's text field and an insert button.

By pressing insert button, the user inserts the data typed into the array.
I have a function which prints all the values of the array into `<p id="demo"></p>` and runs itself every 100 milliseconds in order to be updated with the arrays values.
I also have a reset button to delete every array's value when clicked.

What I want to do is add a delete button next to each array's value in order to be easier for the user to delete the wrong value he inserted.

I am using this code to insert values and print them:

**HTML:**

```
<div align="center">
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Type here!">
    </form>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="Button Insert" onclick="myFunction()" value="Insert">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction3()" value="Reset">
</div>
<p id="demo" align="center"></p>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
var all_values =[];

function myFunction() {
    var temp_val = $("#fname").val();
    all_values.push(temp_val);
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
}

setInterval(function () {
    $("#demo").html(all_values.join("<br>"));
}, 100);

function myFunction3() {
    all_values.length = 0; 
}
```

To be more specific I want something like these things: [iOS example](http://vivacocoa.jp/app/ios/nota-ios/nota-ios-img/delete-row_en.png) [JSFiddle Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/CdLaY/) [JSFiddle Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/b22ww/2/).

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a working example **with your code**, where the values are inserted etc

Comment: Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/jBSscbch . You can run it everywhere you want. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need that array for anything else? Or you just use it do display the values as a HTML?

Comment: I need it for something else too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it the other way around.

Remove `setInterval` as it's really bad way to do such things.
Remove white spaces from the `id` attribute (`id="Button-Insert"`, not `id="Button Insert"`)
[Don't use `onclick` attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Instead, register click event handlers with jQuery

```
// caching is a good practice when you reffer to the same elements multiple times:
var all_values =[], demo = $("#demo"), form = $("#form1")[0], fname = $("#fname");

$('#Button-insert').click(function(){
    var temp_val = fname.val();
    all_values.push(temp_val);
    // create delete button along with the value
    demo.append('<p>'+temp_val+' <button value="'+temp_val+'" type="button" class="del-btn">Delete</button></p>');
    form.reset();
});

$('#Button-reset').click(function(){
    all_values = []; 
    demo.html('');
});

// event delegation for dynamic elements:
demo.on('click', '.del-btn', function(){
    all_values.splice(all_values.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3n5mqabe/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the delete buttons at the same time you create the table.

```
 function loadvalues(){
  var i, button; 
  $('#demo').empty();
  for(i in all_values){
      $('#demo').append(all_values[i]);
      button = $('<button>',{'text':'Delete'}).click(function(){
           all_values.splice(this,1);
           loadvalues();
      }.bind(i)).appendTo('#demo');
      $('#demo').append('<br>');
   }
 }
```

Also you don't need to poll, you could simply add each one on demand with a function like this:

```
 function addVal(){
     var val = $("#fname").val(), i = all_values.length;
     all_values.push(val);

     $('#demo').append(val);
     button = $('<button>',{'text':'Delete'}).click(function(){
            all_values.splice(this,1);
            loadvalues();
    }.bind(i)).appendTo('#demo');
    $('#demo').append('<br>');
 }
```

I had some typos, the code works, 
Check here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbvgpW

Comment: Unfortunately I tried your solution but it didn't work (here is the full code if you want to try it cause I may have done a mistake: http://pastebin.com/jBSscbch). Also, all_values.length = 0; is refering to the reset button which deletes all values from the array. Note that I have to use an array [] cause I need it for something else too. Thanks for your help.